# Spray Json: Convert a Generic type to JsonFormat

Tags: scala, spray-json

I have a class similar to `Pairs`.
I have a trait that converts this `Pairs` class to Json format.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import spray.json._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol

case class Pairs[K, V](key:K, value: V)

trait Convertor[K, V] extends DefaultJsonProtocol{
  implicit val convertor = jsonFormat2(Pairs[K, V])
}
val p = Pairs[String, Int]("One", 1)
println(p.toJson)
```

When I use this trait I get following error to have a convertor for `K` and `V` types.

> error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type
>   Convertor.this.JF[K]
>            implicit val convertor = jsonFormat2(Pairs[K, V])
>                                               ^

But how can I have bring generic data type in scope. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide JsonFormat for both key type and value type.

This code

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
import spray.json._
case class Pairs[K, V](key: K, value: V)
implicit def pairsFormat[K: JsonFormat, V: JsonFormat] = jsonFormat2(Pairs.apply[K, V])
val p = Pairs[String, Int]("One", 1)
println(p.toJson)
```

will print

```
{"key":"One","value":1}
```

Answer (score 1):

`K` and `V` could be everything (`Any`). As you don't have for everything a `Convertor`, you have to restrict `K` and `V`.

```
case class Pairs[K <: PairKey, V <: PairValue](key:K, value: V)
```

Now you need to provide Converters for `PairKey` and `PairValue` and all its children.

You find infos here: [spray-json#jsonprotocol](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#jsonprotocol)